# exe does not find dlls using pyinstaller with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

When I use `pyinstaller --windowed main.py` on my program I get the following error when I run the resulting executable `main.exe`:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
main
├── PyQt5
|   └── Qt
|       └── plugins
|           ├── iconengines
|           ├── imageformats
|           ├── platforms
|           └── printsupport
├── main.exe
└── ...
```

The error disappears when I change it to:

```
main
├── iconengines
├── imageformats
├── platforms
├── printsupport
├── main.exe
└── ...
```

I suspect the program does not look for dlls deep enough.
However I would like to run `pyinstaller --windowed --onefile main.py`.
Of course when I do this I cannot change the folder structure.

How can I get the program to run using the `--onefile` flag?